# Creating folders dynamically with url

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, ipad

I'm creating an app where I have to download some images from a server and store it to use when the network is not available (and to save data).
The problem I'm facing is that I have a base url (`www.url.com/`) and all the image address came from a JSON connection, but it came like this: `Upload/Ctop/GC60V/JPEG/GC60V_concept.jpg`. As I have some different images, each image came with a different path and I need to store it in one of the two ways:

1. Just the filename in the `Documents/Upload/` or
2. Create the folders with the complete path in the Documents directory.

For both ways I have to be able (of course) to recover the images.

What I am doing right now is:
- I check if there is an update in the server. If it exist, I try to erase the `/Upload/` folder and recreate it:

```
// Erase previous images
        NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], @"/Upload/"];

        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]);
        if ([filemgr removeItemAtPath: documentsDirectory error: NULL]  == YES) {
            NSLog(@"Folder removed: %@", documentsDirectory);
        }
```

Then, I receive the JSON data and I try to 'create the folders' and save the new files:

```
// Download of categories images
                if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", URL_BASE, [[categories objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Path"]] isEqualToString:URL_BASE]) {
                    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", URL_BASE, [[categories objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Path"]]];
                    urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                }

                if (urlData)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Starting categories image download...");
                    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);

                    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, [[categories objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Path"]];
                    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                    NSLog(@"Download finished.");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"No categories image to download.");
                }
```

As I understand it, I'm missing the process to correctly create the folders, but I can't figure out how can I do that. Also, I don't know how can I read it.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Create directory before `writeToFile:` by `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];`

Comment: I don't believe it was so simple @Akhilrajtr (actually I do!). It is creating the folders now! but I still have to address the problem with the filename, because I am trying to save the name of the file with the complete path (something like /Upload/Folder/etc/image.jpg) and I believe I have to cut the folders name and just let the image name. Is there any easy way to do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: so you just need `Documents/Upload/imageName.jpg` as path?

Comment: Yes, I think it will be the best way to do that. But if I create the path like you told me, I have to change the name of the file to not contain all the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all when u are saving the image file to disk, each image should hav different name so that u can access it in your application for example,

suppose you are getting the image from server u can save it like below

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
     NSString *picname = [url lastPathComponent];//hear u are getting the image name as the last part of your url
    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/uplpad/%@",picname]; //hear picname is unique for each download, thus u hav different name for each file u saved

 if(imageData != nil)
    {
        NSString *Dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *pngPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",Dir,imagePath]; //path means ur destination contain's  this format -> "/foldername/picname" pickname must be unique
       if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[pngPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]])
       {
           NSError *error;
          [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[pngPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
          if(error)
          {
              NSLog(@"error in creating dir");
          }
      }
        [imageData writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
   }
```

above you are saving the data to disk in upload folder

for retrieving the images u need to use the same image name that is present the file
for example

```
    NSString *Dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *Path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",Dir,InDestination];//hear InDestination contains the path something like "/upload/uniqueImagename"
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:Path];
   if(image)
   { 
     ..do somthing with image
   }
   else
   { 
     ..image not found need to download and save 
   }
```

for removing the folder

```
  NSString *Dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,  YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *pathToFolder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",Dir,@"fbfriends"];

 BOOL remove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pathToFolder error:nil];
 if(remove)
 {
     NSLog(@"success");
 }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"error");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete explanation. Worked perfectly! :)